# Derivative of cross product w.r.t. a vector

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, cross-product

How to compute the derivative of $\vec{a}\times\vec{b}$ w.r.t. $\vec{c}$, all of which are 3D vectors for simplicity? Here $\vec{a}(\vec{c})$ and $\vec{b}(\vec{c})$ are both dependent on $\vec{c}$. I know that the result should be a $3\times3$ matrix. And we cannot simply apply the chain rule as

$$\frac{\partial(\vec{a}\times\vec{b})}{\partial \vec{c}} = \frac{\partial\vec{a}}{\partial\vec{c}} \times \vec{b} + \vec{a} \times \frac{\partial\vec{b}}{\partial\vec{c}}$$

as $\frac{\partial\vec{a}}{\partial\vec{c}}$ would be a matrix then. Is there any analytical expression for the result? For example, $$\frac{\partial\vec{x}}{\partial\vec{x}} = \left[\array{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}\right]$$

Comment: Sorry for my careless mistake. I've edited the question. Could you take another look?

Comment: Can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: Work out the details: compute the coefficients of the vector product, then the jacobian (i.e. partial derivatives of those coefficients by $c_x, c_y$ and $c_z$ in turn). After simplification, you will see that the formula you write is correct, if the vector product $M\times v$ (where $M$ is a matrix and $v$ a vector) is applied column by column.

Comment: It makes most of the time more sense to first work with directional derivatives, and then to try to isolate the direction vector. But I do not see how that could work for $(Mv)\times b$ just in the first term. Note that formulas are well-known if $M$ is skew-symmetric, as this is then a double cross product. But in the most simple case, $M=fg^T$ you get $(Mv)\times b=(g^Tv)(f\times b)$, which looks nice at first, but does not generalize as nicely. Otherwise rigid-body dynamics $I\dot\omega=\omega\times (I\omega)$ would be much easier.

Comment: @LutzLehmann The first column of the jacobian is $\dfrac{\partial(\vec{a}\times\vec{b})}{\partial \vec{c_x}} =\dfrac{\partial\vec{a}}{\partial\vec{c_x}} \times \vec{b} + \vec{a} \times \dfrac{\partial\vec{b}}{\partial\vec{c_x}}$, likewise for the other two. So effectively the jacobian is equivalent to $\dfrac{\partial\vec{a}}{\partial\vec{c}} \times \vec{b} + \vec{a} \times \dfrac{\partial\vec{b}}{\partial\vec{c}}$ computed column-wise.

Comment: The symbolism in the first term is ambiguous, it relates to the columns of the Jacobian, but per matrix-vector multiplication conventions one could be led to use the rows of the Jacobian. So it would be a little better to write this as $- \vec{b} \times \dfrac{\partial\vec{a}}{\partial\vec{c}}+ \vec{a} \times \dfrac{\partial\vec{b}}{\partial\vec{c}}$. @Jean-ClaudeArbaut.

Comment: So the task is to compute$$\lim_{\delta\to 0}\frac{(\vec{a}\times\vec{b})(\vec{c}+\delta\vec v)-(\vec{a}\times\vec{b})(\vec{c})}{\delta}$$for all pairs $(\vec c, \vec v)$?

Answer (score 3):

In tensorial form, we can write
$$
(a\times b)_i=\epsilon_{ijk}a^jb^k,
$$
where $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is the Levi-Civita's symbol. Therefore, what we are looking for, can be expressed as
$$
\frac{\partial (a\times b)_i}{\partial c^\mu}
{=
\frac{\partial\epsilon_{ijk}a^jb^k}{\partial c^\mu}
\\=
\epsilon_{ijk}\frac{\partial a^jb^k}{\partial c^\mu}
\\=
\epsilon_{ijk}\frac{\partial a^j}{\partial c^\mu}b^k+\epsilon_{ijk}a^j\frac{\partial b^k}{\partial c^\mu}
\\\equiv
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial a}{\partial c^1}\times b+a\times\frac{\partial b}{\partial c^1}&
\frac{\partial a}{\partial c^2}\times b+a\times\frac{\partial b}{\partial c^2}&
\frac{\partial a}{\partial c^3}\times b+a\times\frac{\partial b}{\partial c^3}
\end{bmatrix}.
}
$$

Comment: The first equation is off: The LHS is a vector, the RHS is a number

Comment: No it is not. The $j$ and $k$ indices are dummy, whereas $i$ is not, giving rise to a vector.

Comment: IMO the correct notation would be$$(a\times b)_i=\epsilon_{ijk}a^jb^k$$

Comment: Good suggestion. Applied accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$Use an uppercase letter to denote the
$\sf Cross$-$\sf Product\;Matrix$ of a vector, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
b = \m{b_1\\b_2\\b_3} \qquad B = \m{
   0\; & -b_3 &  b_2\; \\
 b_3 &    0\; & -b_1\; \\
-b_2 &  b_1 &    0\;\; \\
} \;=\; -B^T
}$$
Use this to rewrite the desired cross product
(in several different ways)
$$\eqalign{
p &= \LR{a\times b} \;&=\; -\LR{b\times a} \\
 &= Ab \;&=\; -Ba \;\;\;=\; B^Ta \\
}$$
Then calculate its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
dp &= A\:db + B^Tda \qiq
\grad{p}{c} \:=\: A\gradLR{b}{c} \;+\; B^T\!\gradLR{a}{c} \\
}$$