# Taylor Series Expansion of a Vector Cross product

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, taylor-expansion

This is confusing me a little. What is the Taylor series expansion of:

$$f(u,v) = u \times v$$

Around points (i.e., vectors) $u_0$ and $v_0$ up until the first derivative (i.e., no higher order terms than order 2)? Thank you!

Here's what I have so far: so we pick a small values near $(u_0, v_0)$ i.e.,:
$$u = \bar{u} + u_0 $$
$$v = \bar{v} + v_0 $$

we want to express $f(u,v)$ as follows:
$$f(u,v) \approx f(u_0, v_0) + \frac{\partial f (u,v)}{\partial u}\Big|_{(u_0,v_0)}\,\bar{u} + \frac{\partial f (u,v)}{\partial v}\Big|_{(u_0,v_0)}\,\bar{v}$$.

Which means the Taylor series expansion is given as follows:
$$
%
f(u,v) \approx u_0 \times v_0 + \frac{\partial}{ \partial u}(u \times v)\Big |_{(u_0,v_0)}\cdot \bar{u} \ \ + \frac{\partial}{ \partial v}(u \times v)\Big |_{(u_0,v_0)}\cdot \bar{v}
%
$$

$$
= u_0 \times v_0 + (\mathbb{1} \times v_0) \cdot \bar{u} \ \ + (u_0 \times \mathbb{1}) \cdot \bar{v}
$$

where $\mathbb{1}$ is simply a column vector of ones i.e., $\frac{\partial }{\partial u}\begin{bmatrix}u_1 \\u_2 \\u_3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \\1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Is this correct? Or should $\mathbb{1}$ be the idenity matrix $I_{3\times3}$ instead?

Comment: To show that you have put effort, I recommend either editing the post with the progress you made so far in trying to come up with an expansion, or explaining to us about single-variable expansion $f(u)$ about $u$ so that we know what you understand.

Comment: Thank you! I edited the post and put up my answer so far.

Comment: You have some typos. You should have $f(u,v)$ on the left-hand side. I would write $(u_0+\bar u)\times (v_0+\bar v) = u_0\times v_0 + \bar u\times v_0 + u_0\times\bar v + \dots$. Does this agree with your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess @TedShifrin's comment is the direct approach, where you substitute $u = \bar{u} + u_0, v = \bar{v} + v_0$ in the function, expand, and drop terms that are second order and higher (i.e. involve multiplication, or cross product in this case, of at least two of $\bar{u}, \bar{v}$.

Here's my approach, kind of working backwards from the definition. We ultimately want something of the form
$$f(u_0, v_0) + \frac{\partial f (u,v)}{\partial u}\Big|_{(u_0,v_0)}\,\bar{u} + \frac{\partial f (u,v)}{\partial v}\Big|_{(u_0,v_0)}\,\bar{v}, \quad \bar{u} \equiv u - u_0, \; \bar{v} \equiv v - v_0, \; \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Since $u$ is a vector, I don't know how to confidently calculate $\frac{\partial f (u,v)}{\partial u}$. So I start with the fundamental definition of the derivative for scalar variables,
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\Big|_{x_0} = \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{y(x) - y(x_0)}{x - x_0} = \lim_{\bar{x} \to 0} \frac{y(x_0 + \bar{x}) - y(x_0)}{\bar{x}}$$

Now if we try to directly use this formula for our vector situation, we have a problem as we'll be dividing by a vector, which is undefined.
$$\frac{\partial f (u,v)}{\partial u}\Big|_{(u_0,v_0)} = \lim_{\bar{u} \to 0} \frac{f(u_0 + \bar{u},v_0) - f(u_0,v_0)}{\bar{u}}$$

But if we ignore the limit for now and rearrange,
$$\frac{\partial f (u,v)}{\partial u}\Big|_{(u_0,v_0)} \bar{u} = f(u_0 + \bar{u},v_0) - f(u_0,v_0)$$

This we can use in our desired expansion, Eq. \eqref{eq1},
\begin{align}
f(u_0, v_0) + &\left(f(u_0 + \bar{u},v_0) - f(u_0,v_0)\right)+ \left(f(u_0, v_0 + \bar{v}) - f(u_0,v_0)\right) \\&= f(u_0 + \bar{u},v_0) + f(u_0, v_0 + \bar{v}) - f(u_0,v_0)
\end{align}

Applying the function $f(u,v) = u \times v$,
\begin{align}
(u_0 + \bar{u})\times v_0 &+ u_0 \times (v_0 + \bar{v}) - u_0 \times v_0 \\
 &= u_0 \times v_0 + \bar{u}\times v_0 + u_0 \times \bar{v}
\end{align}

So the Taylor series expansion is,
$$f(u,v) \approx u_0 \times v_0 + \bar{u}\times v_0 + u_0 \times \bar{v} $$

*I did drop the limit from the derivative definition earlier, so there could be an error in this derivation, but I at least think the final result is correct

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$Based on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4737557/357854) the relevant derivatives for a cross-product are
$$\eqalign{
f &= f(a,b) \;=\; a\times b \;=\; Ab \;=\; B^Ta \quad \\
}$$
$$\eqalign{
\grad fb &= A &= \m{
   0\; & -a_3   &  a_2\; \\
 a_3   &    0\; & -a_1\; \\
-a_2   &  a_1   &    0\;\; \\
} \\
\grad fa &= B^T &= \m{
   0\; &  b_3   & \:-b_2\; \\
-b_3   &    0\; &  b_1\; \\
 b_2   & \:-b_1   &    0\;\; \\
} \;=\; -B \\
\\
}$$
So the Taylor series centered at $(a_0,b_0)$ yields
$$\eqalign{
f(a,b)
 &= f(a_0,b_0) \;+\; A_0(b-b_0) \;+\; B^T_0(a-a_0) \\
 &= f(a_0,b_0) \;+\; a_0\times(b-b_0) \;-\; b_0\times(a-a_0) \\
 &= f(a_0,b_0) \;+\; a_0\times b \;+\; a\times b_0 \\
}$$